# Leaflet: How can I adjust the width to height ratio of the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet

Here I have the global data and the step for latitude and longitude is 0.5. In this way, I have a 360*720(lat*lng) size data. However, when I map my data as an image overlay on the leaflet map and also use method: map.latLngToLayerPoint for converting the layer point to the geographical map points, I find there will emerge many white stripes in the latitude direction. Obviously, it is caused by the improper scale from 360 to 512 in the lat direction. So I want to change the width to height ratio of the map so that I can keep that when the length of the image overlay is 512, the height of the image is 256 instead of 512 too. Is that any existed method in leaflet for this question?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you show the problem on an example (JSFiddle) ?

Comment: @FranceImage Here is the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/rnwqqayd/

Comment: @FranceImage Here is the problem. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rnwqqayd/)  Hope you can understand my question. Compared to interpolate the point, I want to resize the map tiler because it will give a better display of the original data. This image displays the original data: http://postimg.org/image/ve8sgokb9/. And this image displays sampling result if the data is mapped on the map within the tiler size of 512*512. You can find many white stripes caused by the loss of data due to the 0.5 unit precision. http://postimg.org/image/gtgbgh7mh/. Thank you!!!